# How to display the "ratingValue" and "ratingCount" values ​generated by the KK Star Ratings plugin into my page's recipe ld+json schema

Tags: plugins, post-meta, json, rating

I'm trying to add ld+json schema markup to each recipe page on my site that will automatically pull over the most up to date aggregator rating data (from kk star ratings).  I came across this post ([https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368872/show-the-ratingvalue-and-ratingcount-values-of-kk-star-ratings-plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368872/show-the-ratingvalue-and-ratingcount-values-of-kk-star-ratings-plugin%22)) which has the below code:

```
<?php
//Getter methods

//this will return the base best score like 5 or 10.

function get_best_rating(){
return max((int) get_option('kksr_stars'), 1);
}


//This will return the rating vote count
function get_rating_count($id){
return count_filter(null, $id, null);
}

//This will return the rating score value
function get_rating_score($id){
return score_filter(null, $best, $id, null);
}

//Helper Functions
function count_filter($count, $id, $slug){
if ($slug) {
    return $count;
}

$count = (int) get_post_meta($id, '_kksr_casts', true);

return max($count, 0);
}

function score_filter($score, $best, $id, $slug){
if ($slug) {
    return $score;
}

$count = count_filter(null, $id, null);
$counter = (float) get_post_meta($id, '_kksr_ratings', true);

if (! $count) {
    return 0;
}

$score = $counter / $count / 5 * $best;
$score = round($score, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

return min(max($score, 0), $best);
}
?>
```

Now you can call the getter function like this:

```
$best = get_best_rating();
$count = get_rating_count(get_the_id()); //You must provide post id as param
$score = get_rating_score(get_the_id()); //You must provide post id as param
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've added the first piece of code to my child theme's functions.php file.  Then I've added the calls coding to my ld+json schema markup which I have embedded onto the specific page (see below).

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "recipeCategory": "Drinks",
  "name": "Apple Pie Moonshine Recipe",
  "url": "https://milehidistilling.com/apple-pie-moonshine-recipe/",
  "author": {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "name": "Mile Hi Distilling"},
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "$score = get_rating_score(get_the_id(125070));",
        "bestRating": "$best = get_best_rating();",
        "ratingCount": "$count = get_rating_count(get_the_id(125070));"},
  "prepTime": "PT5M",
  "cookTime": "PT60M",
  "totalTime":"PT90M",
  "recipeYield": "4 quarts",
  "recipeCuisine":"American",
    "nutrition": {
    "@type": "NutritionInformation",
    "servingSize": "4 quarts",
    "calories": "104 calories"
    },
  "datePublished": "2019-07-27",
  "description": "In this guide, we'll be explaining two different step-by-step recipes for making a delicious batch of Apple Pie Moonshine.",
  "keywords": "apple pie moonshine, apple pie moonshine recipe, moonshine recipe, moonshine recipes",
  "image": [
  "https://milehidistilling.com/wp-content/uploads/photos/1x1/Apple-Pie-Moonshine.jpg",
  "https://milehidistilling.com/wp-content/uploads/photos/4x3/Apple-Pie-Moonshine.jpg",
  "https://milehidistilling.com/wp-content/uploads/photos/16x9/Apple-Pie-Moonshine.jpg"
],
  "recipeIngredient": [
    "8 cups of moonshine (120 proof) or vodka (80 proof) if you want a less potent final product",
    "5 cans of apple juice concentrate",
    "3-4 cups of brown sugar",
    "10 cinnamon sticks",
    "Apple pie spice",
    "Dried ginger",
    "Vanilla bean",
    "1 apple"
  ],
  "recipeInstructions":[{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"1. For the first step, you pour all 5 cans of apple juice concentrate into a large pot."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"2. Add 3-4 cups of brown sugar (depending on how sweet you want your batch to turn out)."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"3. Next, add in your 10 cinnamon sticks, cut your apple into 4 pieces and add them into the mix as well.  If you’d like to create a more complex flavor profile for your apple pie flavored moonshine you can also add 1 pinch of apple pie spice, 1/4 cup of dried ginger, and 1-2 sticks of vanilla bean into the batch.  Be aware that a small amount of each of these goes a long way!"},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"4. Bring your mixture to a low simmer. Cover your pot with a lid and reduce heat. Let your mixture simmer for one-hour. After that, remove your pot from the burner and allow the mixture to cool down."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"5. Once the mixture cools down, you can pour in your 8 cups of moonshine.  *Be sure to wait until the mixture cools down before pouring in your moonshine.  Stir to completely mix the moonshine in with your apple concentrate batch."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"6. Next slowly pour your moonshine mixture into your 4 quart jars.  Be sure to use a cheesecloth to filter the moonshine/apple concentrate mixture as you pour it.  Add 1 cinnamon stick and 1/4th of an apple that was previously in your mixture to each jar."},{"@type":"HowToStep","text":"7. Congrats! You can enjoy your apple pie flavored moonshine immediately. For a more complex and aged flavor, seal and store the jars in your refrigerator for 2-3 weeks before you enjoy your batch. Be sure to stir up the mix well before serving to avoid an uneven pour of shine."}]
}
</script>
```

All I get when I check my structured data is:
[image]
So I think this tells me that the functions.php code isn't pulling that kk star ratings data correctly or I'm not calling the data correctly with the code I have in my ld+json schema.  Either way it's not proving the actual aggregator rating variables for the recipe schema.

KK Star Ratings is already dynamically producing a separate schema markup as a CreativeWorkSeries with the specific variables for Aggregator rating (ratingValue, bestRating, ratingCount).  I just want to target those same dynamically loaded variables for my recipe schema markup.  I hope I have explained this clearly.  Thanks to anyone who can help me out with this.  Let me know if I can clarify any details.

Comment: Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes.

Comment: I understand, however, I found the original post covering this topic (which I linked to) on this site, so I thought I may find a solution here.

Comment: Looks like your PHP code is not executed. Is it inside `<?php` and `?>`? Can you post the complete part where you're outputting the ld-json in the functions.php?

Comment: I do have <?php and ?> added at the beginning and the end of the php code in the functions.php file within the child theme.  I'm not sure what you mean by "outputting the ld-json in the functions.php"